# Block number is not up to date or close to the latest block height

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

My question is why my blockchain block number is not up to date meaning is not sync to the latest block number, latest block number is 17000xxxx but mine is 1500xxxxx which is not close to latest block number which is the block height.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of geth? One possibility is that you are in an abandoned fork.

Comment: @Ismael we are using older version, but after an update. The blockchain number is not to up data during syncing.

Comment: @Ismael our version is 1.10.15, so what I'm curious is that if our version is too old therefore the blocknumber is not upadating, what if we replace with the new version of geth, will there be any troubles or issues occured like different version will cause file replacing errors, or lose data or other troubles?

Answer (score 0):

Hey @theunknowthinker I think your node is stuck & not getting synced fast enough, & way to fix could be to update the infra if running the node in house or change provider.

You can maybe also just use web3 sdk's and get ahead
Like :

```
// yarn add @tatumcom/js
import { TatumSDK, Ethereum, Network } from '@tatumcom/js'
const tatum = await TatumSDK.init<Ethereum>({network: Network.ETHEREUM})
const latestBlock = await tatum.rpc.blockNumber()
```

Comment: Thank you for providing answer but I'm afraid this is not the answer that I want, we are using older version of geth: 1.10.15, does it cause the problem for syncing the block number? meaning that our version is out of date or not compatible to the current geth version?

Comment: the question is that when we creating our own block during syncing, the data is not sync with etheruem meaning that the block number is remain 15xxxxxx during syncing and not up to date which close to current highest block: 17xxxxxxx, so this issues cause us to hand work on everything to update the data or info.

Answer (score 0):

There was the Shapella fork on April 2023. You'll need at least geth v1.11.5 to be on the right side of the fork. If you haven't updated you are on the wrong side of the fork.

See the announcement on the Ethereum's blog https://blog.ethereum.org/2023/03/28/shapella-mainnet-announcement.